# In what sense are life permitting constants improbable?

Tags: probability

It is said that life permitting constants of the universe are improbable in the sense that if they were different, life would not have arose. As per the fine tuning argument, if there is an intelligent designer that designed it, it would explain the supposed improbability.

But in what sense are they improbable?

1.) Usually when we talk about something being improbable, there’s an implicit assumption that it could have been the case otherwise. A dice has a 1/6 probability of landing on 1 but from what we know about physical laws, it could have physically landed on another number. It could of course also have spontaneously combusted into a bird while in air but this isn’t considered to be physically possible. We don’t count this as a possible outcome. So why should we count other possible constants as possible outcomes? There’s no evidence they’re even possible

2.) If the argument is that it’s improbable in a logical sense, in that it’s not impossible to imagine other constants, then why aren’t other outcomes that are also logically possible considered part of the equation. For example, we can imagine a universe running in complete chaos with no laws. Or a universe with no constants. Or a universe that runs on one law for a second then changes to another law to another second. There are literally infinite possibly ways we can imagine existence to materialize. Why aren’t these considered possible outcomes?

3.) If the argument is that life is valuable as a property to us, and a designer would supposedly create a universe harboring life, isn’t this presupposing what we’re trying to prove. Why suppose that a designer exists in the first place and that he would create life, especially in the form in which we see it?

4.) Why does the designer get to enjoy the privilege of just brutely existing eternally? If it can, then why can’t fine tuned parameters?

Comment: In the sense that if you make constants into parameters and keep the same physical laws the region in the parameter space that permits life (as we know it) has very small Lebesgue measure. So even a very conservative interpretation of "other possibilities" has life hitting the bull's eye on a very large dartboard. And we routinely vary background parameters (within reasonable bounds, which include keeping the laws of physics as is) to assess the likelihood of what happened in everyday situations.

Comment: Why do the physical laws get to be the same? The dartboard example doesn't work since we already know apriori that it's physically possible to hit other parts of the dartboard

Comment: Each constant is it's own case, depending on how accurately we know it, & sensitivity of consequences to variations in it, & guesses about how it could have varied. You are just asking what the Fine Tuning problem is, & so should just read a general introduction like https://plato.stanford.edu/entries/fine-tuning/ While considering it's implications absolutely is philosophy, it's origins are in physics, where clear parameters & methodology preclude the open speculation you speak of

Comment: @thinkingman: You miss the point. *Somewhere got hit*, our universe started with a set of the 19 or so fundamental independent constants. We don't *know* other options were possible - there could be deeper physics, deeper reasons they had to be what they were, & then we'll have fewer fundamental constants as they unify. But, it looks suspcious how precisely *this set* of values enables conditions for life, & so we can consider that, with various secondary assumptions/guesses

Comment: The essence of science is to continue to as "why is this the way it is" questions.  Your proposal in part 4 is to abandon science.  I regularly see atheists condemning the religious for rejecting science if it ever challenges their dogma. however, most religious actually try to figure out if their religion can accommodate science, and non-literalist religious do NOT reject it.    In contrast, I am seeing a near-instant rejections of science by you, and this has been true for other atheists, AT THE FIRST POSSIBLE CHALLENGING IMPLICATION OF SCIENCE!!!

Answer (score 1):

1. I interpret the claim as one of logical probability rather than frequentist probability, so the fact that there is only one known trial is not relevant. Logically, there is a wide range of values that those parameters could have taken, each of which is equally probable. The issue is how it happened to be that the parameters are in the extraordinaly limited range that is friendly to life.

Note: It doesn't help to suggest that maybe all of the values weren't equally probable, because that implies that there is some law of nature N that restricts the possibilities. In this case the probabilistic argument then applies to N.

2. Those other features of the universe that you mention could only make a life-friendly universe less probable if they were considered, making the argument stronger. I presume that the reason they are not usually considered is some combination of (a) it is hard to calculate probabilities for those kinds of features and (b) the argument is strong enough already.
3. The argument does not presuppose that the universe would be designed for harboring life. That's like finding a watch in the sand and saying, "I can't presume that this was designed because to do so would be to presuppose that the designer wanted to create a timepiece, and that would be a circular argument." Rather, you first discover that it is a  timepiece, and then ask whether that timepiece is likely to have come into being from unguided processes of nature or if it is more likely to have been deliberately created. There is nothing circular about this.
4. The argument is based on our understanding of the physical universe. It's not the sort of argument that applies to other modes of existence. For example, it wouldn't make sense to argue that the number five is improbable because it is a prime number that is the sum of all smaller prime numbers. Numbers aren't the sort of things that could have been otherwise. I believe the standard Christian theology says that God also isn't the sort of thing that could have been otherwise. God, having no physical properties, not even location or a time of existence, is no more like a physical object than he is like a number.

Comment: Saying that the constants are equally likely is just a particular kind of chance process: a uniform one. If you get to assert that all values are equally likely, I can get to assert any distribution too.

Comment: In regards to God, how can you ever say that Him doing anything is more likely than anything caused by a chance process?

Comment: @temptrt, my answer already addresses both issues. For your first comment, see the Note after section 1. For the second, see section 3.

Comment: @temptrt -- Physicists consider the constants of our universe to be the result of random draws, from a wide range of possible values.  They are contingent. They don't know the distribution, and have no reason to postulate anything other than random.  The massive difference in order of magnitude of the four basic forces, and of particle masses, support that the range things "could have been" is very very large.  Accept that, and almost all physicists do, and one immediately encounters the Fine Tuning Argument. Most of the range of each free variable could not support a universe with life.

Comment: @temptrt -- this is why the Multiverse hypothesis has become so popular among physicists, despite its untestability. If there are infinite universes, then by the Anthropic Principle, all life will be in a very unlikely universe.  Multiverse, however, must face the question of whether it is untestable and therefore pseudoscience.